# VBA Copy and Paste Formatting for all Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I try to write really simple script to copy original worksheet (ORIGINAL_NOCHANGE) and paste the formatting only other sheet.
In the ORIGINAL_NOCHANGE, there are some column merged together, and some column having the conditional formatting.

This is the original structure of ORIGINAL_NOCHANGE :

[image]

COPY1 and COPY2 are the copy of ORIGINAL_NOCHANGE, but has no format like the original one (my Python script cannot copy the Excel formatting).

After I run my VBA script :

```
Sub TrySecond()
        
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        
        'Worksheets("ORIGINAL_NOCHANGE").Activate
        Worksheets("ORIGINAL_NOCHANGE").Range("A1:AA71").Copy
        
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "ORIGINAL_NOCHANGE" Then
                    'ws.Range("AC1") = "Are You Kidding Me"
                    Range("A1:P17").Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

the ORIGINAL_NOCHANGE has been changed into this structure, which I really don't want :
[image]

but nothing happend in COPY1 and COPY2!

Note that my python script will copy hundreds of ORIGINAL_NOCHANGE worksheet but due to the limitation of package inside, it couldn't copy the formatting.
Putting here as somebody might be suggesting me to copy the original manually.

I'm not sure what's the mistake in my script. Can you please help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to refer to the current worksheet (in the loop) with `ws.Range("A1:P17").Select` (note the `ws`). But I don't think it's going to result in what you want. Probably the best would be to copy the worksheet, rename it and clear its contents. Try to clarify what it is you desire e.g. by posting an image of what `COPY1` and `COPY2` should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formats to New Worksheets

- Adjust the values in the constants section (and the workbook).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FormatsToNewWorksheets()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const sName As String = "ORIGINAL_NOCHANGE"
    Const dNamesList As String = "COPY1,COPY2"
    
    ' Create a reference to the workbook containing this code.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    ' Write the names from the list to the Destination Names Array.
    Dim dNames() As String: dNames = Split(dNamesList, ",")
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim dws As Worksheet ' (Current) Destination Worksheet
    Dim n As Long ' Destination Names Counter
    
    ' Loop through the elements (names) of the Destination Names Array.
    For n = 0 To UBound(dNames)
        ' Attempt to create a reference to the (current) Destination Worksheet.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dNames(n))
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Delete the (current) Destination Worksheet if it exists.
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then ' exists
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'Else ' doesn't exist
        End If
        ' Create the (current) Destination Worksheet
        ' (a copy of the Source Worksheet)
        ' after all existing sheets (at the last position).
        sws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        ' Modify the (current) Destination Worksheet.
        With ActiveSheet
            .Name = dNames(n)
            .UsedRange.ClearContents ' or not?
        End With
    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Ouh 1 more question, the .UsedRange.ClearContents clean up everything including the template bold word. How can I prevent it from cleaning the template word, only clean the data insert?

Comment: Create a constant containing the addresses of the ranges whose contents you want to clear, e.g.: `Const cAddress As String = "A3,D2:L4,D10:N13"` (add more) and use `.Range(cAddress).ClearContents` instead.

Comment: Can I contact you real time somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your worksheet, and select `Move or Copy` then tick `create a copy`, then you can create as many sheets as you want with the same format without VBA ....and you can create this worksheet to other workbook also....

[image]

If you still prefer VBA code, here is the function you can use, same as what i am doing just now:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I know this, but actually I let my Python script to do that (using beautifulsoup and panda). So rather than to go manually, I'm searching for automate way. :D

Comment: You can check my edited answer, it do the same function as I mention